# C4D R20 Movie Render Channel render Issue

Tags: cinema4d

I use C4D R20, when I render a movie of any format, the alpha channel renders as a separate movie file. This did not happen with R19, R17, 13, it use to render the alpha channel embedded in the same movie file so when I import that file in any movie editing software, the movie came with a transparent background. When I render a Static Tiff file it saves the alpha channel in the PSD or Tiff file no problem, and yes I know there is a check button to render alpha channel, I have tried everything and not sure if I'm the only one with this issue or it is supposed to be this way.

Comment: You should go to video production SE with this question. But then why anyone would render movie files directly from a 3D software is the question to as oneself. Why would a folder be less manageable than a file? And why would you want to sacrafice random lookup speed for a intermediate asset anyway?

Comment: Video editing is off-topic here. Sorry about that.  Try Video Production Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is not about video editing at all, my question is why cinema 4d R20 rendering a separate channel on movie render. I'm wondering how i can fix the setting so the alpha channel is imbedded in the movie render instead of a separate file.

Comment: Sorry but it kind of is. You are asking about video formats and how to get alpha transparency in those formats.  This is not graphic design question. I've flagged it for migration to Video Production SE.

Comment: I’m not around my laptop or I’d open up C4D and give you a step-by-step, but off the top of my head, I’d say the codecs are your main culprit. Try exporting prores 4444, and make sure the alpha channel checkbox is ticked.  Also be sure the player you’re using to review the output supports transparency.